# FFMPEG restart live stream recording

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, recording

Is there any way to restart recording live stream automatically when ffmpeg stop it?

ex. There is a live url and I want to record it but after some mins stop recording because of some reasons I need something to restart recording automatically

```
ffmpeg -i "url" -segment_time 1800 -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 -strftime 1 "output-%H-%M-%S.mp4"
```

Comment: Put it in  `while` loop, or better still fix the reasons why it stops in the first place.

Comment: Unknown reason ...
error:
 Failed to reload playlist 0